# cannot remove disk/partition name

Tags: partition

I have partially overwritten my system disk with a copy of CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1708.iso (wrong /dev/sdX in the dd command). I since recovered from this and I notice that in Ubuntu 16.04 /dev/sdb1 (which is in fact a swap partition and should not have a name) is given the name "CentOS 7 x86_64":

```
$ ls -l /dev/disk/by-label/              
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 May  4 12:29 Backup -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 May  4 12:29 centos7 -> ../../sdb2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 May  4 12:29 CentOS\x207\x20x86_64 -> ../../sdb1   <===== ? swap partition
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 May  4 12:29 data -> ../../sdb5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 May  4 12:29 Data -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 May  4 12:29 ubuntu -> ../../sdb3
```

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 on another drive which also assigns this name to a partition on drive /dev/sdb :

```
$ ls -l /dev/disk/by-label/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 May  4 14:16 Backup -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 May  4 14:16 centos7 -> ../../sdb2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 May  4 14:16 CentOS\x207\x20x86_64 -> ../../sdb4 <=== ? extended partition
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 May  4 14:16 data -> ../../sdb5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 May  4 14:16 Data -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 May  4 14:16 ubuntu -> ../../sdb3
```

This time it is /dev/sdb4 which the extended partition container and hence should not have any name either.

Search as I may I did not find where this names comes from and how to get rid of it.

The trouble is that when I try to install a CentOS 7 (from a USB key) the installer scripts looks for a disk labeled "CentOS 7 x86_64" and picks a partition on /dev/sdb rather than the USB key (which is at /dev/sdc in my system).

Come someone help me to solve this issue ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If `/dev/sdb1` is a swap parition, then you can update the label using `mkswap`.  This will re-format the swap partition; there may be other options to avoid that:

```
# swapoff /dev/sdb1
# mkswap -L swap_part /dev/sdb1
# swapof /dev/sdb1
```

Here, 'swap_part' is the new label:

```
$ ls -l /dev/disk/by-label
...
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 May 8 09:32 swap_part -> ../../sdb1
...
```

If you want to remove the label all together, you can set it to the empty string:

```
# mkswap -L "" /dev/sdb1
```

Comment: I also had to change the mounting of the swap partition in /etc/fstab as the UUID of the partition was modified. HOWEVER this has not changed anything : after a reboot ls /dev/disk/by-label/ still shows "CentOS 7 x86_64" as pointing to  /dev/sdb1 ...

Comment: I had used an empty label but I have now also tried with a non-empty label: it does not make a difference.

Comment: @Frederic When I run those commands, the content of `/dev/disk/by-label` updates dynamically.  I see the changes immediately.  Is `sdb4` the partition that you want to have that label?

Comment: no, I don't want /dev/sdb4 to have this label it just happened and I only see this label on /dev/sdb4 when I boot the Ubuntu 14.04 on /dev/sda3. /dev/sdb4 is the MBR extended partion container which contains /dev/sdb5 with an ext4 file system labeled "data".